# Autorotate stopped working in tablet mode. Gnome 40 21.10

Tags: gnome, touchscreen, display-rotation

Updated Lenovo yoga 6 to Ubuntu 21.10. Gnome 40. Doesn't autorotate/go into tablet mode. Is there a fix to this? it lacks the "disable/enable autorotate" button and the on screen keyboard doesn't appear when in tablet mode.The iio-sensor-proxy service is running and "monitor-sensor" is giving the correct output when rotating the screen.

Mentions in the ubuntu 21.10 guide that there should be a autorotate button. but it disappeared on my computer after the update. (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html.en)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when using wayland in combination with a Yoga 520. Now switched to xorg and all is working.You can select a xorg session in the logon screen.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: On my Ubuntu 21.10 there is no option to log into xorg. But xorg can be forced as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop) by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and setting wayland to `false`.